# Library with large number of parameters

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, frameworks, model, shared-libraries

I'm developing a library to be used by myself and third parties. To initialise this library I'll need to pass on a fairly large number of mandatory parameters. I don't know how many in total yet, but I'm already at 9.

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to pass on those parameters.

1) Pass each parameter, one by one. This will become unwieldy and error prone.

2) Make available one constant per parameter and make the library require a hash table, with each constant being the key to the value.

3) Create a model object with all fields and make that available to the user.

Number 2 and 3 seem to be the best although I'm not sure I've seen any of them implemented anywhere else.

Comment: You might use a structure. However, in ARC, you can't use object pointers as structure fields...

Comment: Not much difference between a struct and a simple Objective-C class then. And the class is easier to manage, no?

Comment: Yes, in this case there is not much difference between a struct and a ObjC class, despite the extra memory space required by the class comparing it to a structure. But this is not a critical situation, so overheading is not a problem here and an object would do it well, not to mention the problem of using pointers to objects in structures, under ARC, if this is the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your 3. looks promising.**

Passing one object with all the 9 or even more values will be readable.

Also if you  need to send similar kind of values you can send array or dictionary.

Comment: It would have to be a dictionary, as the values need to be labelled.